# Simple Forms association with specific class

Tags: checkbox, simple-form

At the moment I have something like this

```
<%= f.association :interest_label_levels, :as => :check_boxes %>
```

which produces this

```
...
<label class="checkbox"><input class="check_boxes optional" 
id="recommender_search_term_interest_label_level_ids_2" 
name="recommender_search_term[interest_label_level_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2">Snow 
sports</label>
...
```

Now I would like to add some class names. I got it already working for select inputs but I want to have check_boxes.

I know you can modify the label or value by putting in a label_method or value_method like this:

```
<%= f.association :interest_label_levels, :as => :check_boxes, :label_method => lambda { 
|interest_label_level| interest_label_level.interest_two_label.name } %>
```

But I still can't modify the class. How is this possible?

Comment: did you try setting `item_wrapper_class`? `<%= f.association :interest_label_levels, :as => :check_boxes, :item_wrapper_class => 'sdf' %>`

Comment: thx for your comment. this actually adds a class to the wrapper and not to the specific checkboxes. so I want to give each check_box a class.